# Parse string into multiple variables

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays, string, parsing

I am working on an application that is pulling a list of all file names from a specific directory and needs to then parse the file name into multiple variables to then be submitted to a database.

How can I parse the string file name into multiple variables?

**EX Files:**

2014_31_12_09_36AM_15555555555_108

2014_31_12_09_39AM_108_15555555555

2014_31_12_09_17AM_102_108

The file name contains year, day, month, hour, minutes (with AM/PM), and a 3 digit or 11 digit number, followed by another 3 or 11 digit number

All file names are stored in an array after the directory is scanned.

```
private void ParseFileNames()
    {
        string Year = "";
        string Day = "";
        string Month = "";
        string Hour = "";
        string Minute = "";
        string Called = "";
        string Calling = "";

        //Loop through scanned file names and parse them one at a time.
        for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] parsedFileName = fileNames[i].Split('_');
            Year = parsedFileName[0];
            Day = parsedFileName[1];
            Month = parsedFileName[2];
            Hour = parsedFileName[3];
            Minute = parsedFileName[4];
            Called = parsedFileName[5];
            Calling = parsedFileName[6];

            //open DB connection and submit each individual parsed file data into DB

            //Move file from toIndexPath to IndexedPath
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: “Better” how? Able to handle misformatted names? Storing dates as dates instead of strings? Using fewer characters?

Comment: I am planning to convert the date into a date instead of a string, as well as the time (separate from the date?) so that they can be searched.

Answer (score 0):

you could return a class like this

```
public class FileData
{
    public int Year {get;set;}
    public int Day  {get;set;}
    public int Month  {get;set;}
    public int Hour  {get;set;}
    public int Minute  {get;set;}
    public int Called  {get;set;}
    public int Calling  {get;set;}

    public FileData(string[] parsedInfo)
    {
        Year = Convert.ToInt32(parsedInfo[0]);
        // and so on with other member to load
    }
}
```

then simply call the following to get a `List<FileData>` :

```
var listFileData = fileNames.Select(fn=> new FileData(fn.Split('_'))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is shorter, I dont know about better, but at least you get a Date Time

```
    //This code is just for testing the strings,  delete these 4 after testing.
    var stringList = new List<string>();
    stringList.Add("2014_31_12_09_36AM_15555555555_108");
    stringList.Add("2014_31_12_09_39AM_108_15555555555");
    stringList.Add("2014_31_12_09_17AM_102_108");

    var allFileDate = new List<FileData>();
    foreach (var item in stringList)
    {
        var dt = item.Split('_');
        var timeCombined = string.Concat(dt[2], "/", dt[1],"/", dt[0]," ", dt[3], ":", dt[4]);
        allFileDate.Add(new FileData {Date = Convert.ToDateTime(timeCombined), Called = dt[5], Calling = dt[6]});
    }
```

And your class

```
    public class FileData
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Called { get; set; }
        public string Calling { get; set; }    
    }
```

All data validation in there and it's alright.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to do this?

'better' is pretty subjective. there's always a better way depending on what you want. In your case I would not be writing code to parse your filenames at all, and you'd be making a lot of round trips to populate your table one row at a time.

I would instead just use a bulk load command, e.g.: `LOAD DATA ... INTO TABLE ... LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '_'`